# Mocking a class property set in the constructor using Sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, es6-class

I'm trying to mock a class property that is set to a default value inside the constructor

```
class Files {
  constructor(queueNumber = 0) {
    this.queueNumber = queueNumber;
    this.dir = 'JiraResults';
    if (!fs.existsSync(this.dir)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(this.dir);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

The constructor creates directories and files based on the `dir` property and for the tests, I want another directory, so I don't need to move the real directory to run the tests.

I tried many approaches to replace the property and all of them kept failing with different errors from Sinon.

## First attempt:

```
const tempDir = 'JiraResults-TEMP';
let stubDir;

describe('Files', () => {
  before(() => {
    stubDir = sinon.stub(Files.prototype.constructor, 'dir').value(tempDir);
  }
  ...
}
```

With this I get the error `TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property dir`

## Second attempt

```
const tempDir = 'JiraResults-TEMP';
let stubDir;

describe('Files', () => {
  before(() => {
    stubDir = sinon.stub(Files.prototype, 'dir').value(tempDir);
  }
  ...
}
```

With this I get the error `TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property dir`

## Third attempt

```
const tempDir = 'JiraResults-TEMP';
let stubDir;

describe('Files', () => {
  before(() => {
    stubDir = sinon.stub(Files.prototype, 'this').value({
      dir: sinon.stub().returnsThis(tempDir),
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

With this I get the error `TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property this`

---

I also tried other things and never got to the point of having the property replaced.

I looked into Sinon documentation, but none of the examples seems to apply to a constructor class.

Could anyone give me a working example on how can I replace this property?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the value of the `dir` property directly so that the method under test will use the stubbed `dir`.

E.g.

`files.js`:

```js
class Files {
  constructor(queueNumber = 0) {
    this.queueNumber = queueNumber;
    this.dir = "JiraResults";
  }

  mkdir() {
    console.log("make dir: ", this.dir);
  }
}

module.exports = Files;
```

`files.test.js`:

```js
const Files = require("./files");
const sinon = require("sinon");

describe("Files", () => {
  it("should use stubbed dir", () => {
    sinon.spy(console, "log");
    const instance = new Files();
    instance.dir = "stubbed dir";
    instance.mkdir();
    sinon.assert.calledWith(console.log, "make dir: ", "stubbed dir");
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
Files
make dir:  stubbed dir
    ✓ should use stubbed dir


  1 passing (7ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 files.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 files.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

**UPDATE:**

I don't think it's possible. Let's take a look at below example:

`files.js`:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

class Files {
  constructor(queueNumber = 0) {
    this.queueNumber = queueNumber;
    console.log("before: ", this.dir);
    this.dir = "JiraResults";
    console.log("after: ", this.dir);
    if (!fs.existsSync(this.dir)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(this.dir);
    }
  }
}

Files.prototype.dir = "";

module.exports = Files;
```

`files.test.js`:

```js
const Files = require("./files");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const fs = require("fs");

describe("Files", () => {
  it("should use stubbed dir to mkdir", () => {
    sinon.stub(fs, "existsSync").returns(false);
    sinon.stub(fs, "mkdirSync");
    sinon.stub(Files.prototype, "dir").value("stubbed dir");
    console.log("stub dir");
    new Files();
    sinon.assert.calledWith(fs.existsSync, "stubbed dir");
    sinon.assert.calledWith(fs.mkdirSync, "stubbed dir");
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
  Files
stub dir
before:  stubbed dir
after:  JiraResults
    1) should use stubbed dir to mkdir


  0 passing (13ms)
  1 failing

  1) Files
       should use stubbed dir to mkdir:
     AssertError: expected existsSync to be called with arguments 
JiraResults stubbed dir 
      at Object.fail (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:106:21)
      at failAssertion (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:65:16)
      at Object.assert.(anonymous function) [as calledWith] (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:91:13)
      at Context.it (src/stackoverflow/59303752/files.test.js:1:2345)
```

We can make a stub for property `dir` successfully before instantiating the class `Files`. But after we instantiated the class `Files`. It will assign "JiraResults" string to property `dir` which means it will replace the `stubbed dir` to `JiraResults`.

There are three options:

1. Set a default value for property `dir`, `Files.prototype.dir = 'JiraResults'`(But it is based on your requirement.)
2. Pass `dir` as a parameter to the constructor of `Files` class.
3. Extract the `fs` operations to a method like the original anwser.

Then, it will be easier to make a stub for unit testing.

Comment: I thought about this approach, but the problem I have is that the constructor creates the folder. So, changing the property after the constructor has been run is not an option. I updated the question to show this. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Makes sense... I'll change the constructor to have a default value but allow a replacement for my tests. Thanks a lot